# Function overload with varying return values not accepted

Tags: typescript

I do not understand why the following implementation is not accepted. I hope you can help.

```
type F = {
    (a: number): string
    (a: string, b: number): number
}
const func: F = (numberOrString: string | number, b?: number): string | number => {
    if (typeof numberOrString === 'number')
        return numberOrString.toString();
    else if (b !== undefined)
        return numberOrString.length + b;
    throw new Error("Can't happen");
};
```

The error message is:

```
Type '(numberOrString: string | number, b?: number | undefined) => string | number' is not assignable to type 'F'.
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it should be, right? But as it says in the [function overloads section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)...

> The implementation signature must also be *compatible* with the overload signatures.

*(Their emphasis)*

A return type of `string | number` isn't compatible with a return type of `string` (your first overload) or `number` (your second).

In practice, this often means that your implementation signature — particularly the return type — is much broader than you would otherwise write. That's okay, because the code *using* the function doesn't see the implementation signature, just the overload signatures. While you can use unions for the parameter types (as you have), you can't use them for the return type because it won't be compatible.

In your example, we can solve the problem by changing the return type to `any` (as you probably already know):

```typescript
type F = {
    (a: number): string;
    (a: string, b: number): number;
};
const func: F = (numberOrString: string | number, b?: number): any => {
    if (typeof numberOrString === 'number')
        return numberOrString.toString();
    else if (b !== undefined)
        return numberOrString.length + b;
    throw new Error("Can't happen");
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UDeAoK6oAoCGAuKAdgK4C2ARhAE4CU+AzsJQJYEDmA3GhjvYy6wBooZfMXJVahUhUqcAvpwDGAewIMoAMyIFF+OIkxiZAeUoBlPm17M2UAD5TxlIWQD8o6RPzYCIBAD5kLnQmDSxQSGUwoypTCxtWBHhEAHIYyhTqYIx0SghgIkoCRxNzS1YAOmBleP5Mak4ciAAbOmhQrDIoAEJkqG0AEwgNFggBrJycvIKiktiyhIrmiDZgAAsoAGphRox1ymUAd0IIY4BRSgPKTAAiAGEfFOAoNewwSAIbhpQFIA)

Normally `any` is something to avoid, but in a function overload *implementation* signature, it's okay and sometimes necessary.

Comment: Thank you T.J. 'any' does the job, but it is a bit broad, isn't it?
Your statement seem somewhat strange:
<cite>
A return type of string | number isn't compatible with a return type of string or number.
</cite>

Comment: @JohannesSchacht - Yes, I said the return type was broad in the answer, and why: Your implementation says it returns `string | number`, and that is incompatible with an overload signature that returns `string` (and separately, it's incompatible with a signature that returns `number`). `string | number` isn't assignable to `string`, and separately, `string | number` isn't assignable to `number`.

Comment: @JohannesSchacht - That is, your original (which, to be clear, is how I would have written it at first too :-) ) basically tries to assign a `(/*...*/) => string | number` function to a variable that allows **either** a `(/*...*/) => string` function **or** a `(/*...*/) => number` function (not both).